# Symfony 3.4 - add an element to form at specific position in controller

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have to manage 2 entities: `map` and `layergroup`. In layergroup obj, there is a field that refer to map.
I generated code by `cmd` and modified `layerGroupType` in form folder to delete `mapid` element that will be added in `Controller` so I can customize the list of choice that I get from map table.

**Following is the code: 
In form/layerGroupType.php:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('groupName', TextType::class, array('label'=>Group Name:','label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label'],'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']))
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label'=>Description:','label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label'],'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']));
}
```

**In  the Controller:**

```
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\WmapBundle\Form\LayerGroupType', $layerGroup);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $maps = $em->getRepository('AppBundleWmapBundle:Map')->findAll();
    $mapsArr=array();
    $noMaps=count($maps);
    if ($noMaps>0){
        foreach ($maps as $map) {
            $mapsArr[(string)$map->getMapTitle()]=(string)$map->getId();
        }
    }
    $form->add('mapid',ChoiceType::class,array(
        'before' => 'description',
        'label'=>'In the map:',
        'choices'  => $mapsArr,
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label'],'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'])
    );
```

Everything is good. However, the new element is put to the end of form when I rendered. It is not good for user experience. I want to put this new element between `'groupName'` and `'description'` element.

How could I do? Please help!!!

Comment: If it is a problem of rendering, can you post the code of the view?

Comment: In the view: I use for loop to go through all form item and create the form element by: {{ form_widget(input) }}. I think the problem is that the position when I add new element always is at the end. Now I want to change it